# Passing Generic Type with Constraint as Type<Constraint>

Tags: c#, generics

If I have a `GenericClass` with a type constraint of `where T : BaseType`, why can't I pass it as `GenericClass<BaseType>`?

```
class GenericClass<T> where T : BaseType
{
    void Method()
    {
        new UtilityClass().Method(this);
    }
}

class UtilityClass
{
    internal void Method(GenericClass<BaseType> genericClass)
    {
    }
}
```

The static analyser error:

```
Cannot convert from 'GenericsPoc.GenericClass<T>' to 
'GenericsPoc.GenericClass<GenericsPoc.BaseType>'
```

I didn't expect this since `UtilityClass<T>` the `T` has to inherit from `BaseClass`.

Comment: This is circular and therefore not resolvable for the compiler. Maybe it works with a explicit cast?

Comment: @Nikolaus thanks, we can't use casts, since that breaks in certain cases and cause rutime errors.

Comment: You tried it? Like this:  `new UtilityClass().Method((GenericClass<Basetype>)this )` it shouldn’t break anytime, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify `UtilityClass` so that the method also passes down the generic type:

```
internal void Method<T>(GenericClass<T> genericClass) where T: BaseType
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, surprisingly this works without modifying GenericClass. I expected the call to be UtilityClass.Method<T>(this).

Comment: @Manuel: That is because the compiler can infer the type in this case.

Answer (score 4):

This question is asked every day.  One more time!

```
class Cage<T> where T : Animal
{
  public void Add(T t) { ... }
}
```

Now your question is: why is this illegal?

```
Cage<Animal> cage = new Cage<Gerbil>();
```

Because this line is legal:

```
cage.Add(new Tiger());
```

`Cage<Animal>` has a method `Add` which takes `Animal`.  A `Tiger` is an `Animal` so that must be legal.  But that means that we just put a tiger into a gerbil cage.

Since that line must be legal and it causes a type error, some *other* line must be illegal, and now you know which one it is.

The feature you want is called *generic covariance* and it *is* legal in C# when:

- The generic type is an interface or delegate
- The varying type argument is a reference type
- The interface or delegate has been marked as safe for variance.

For example:

```
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = new List<Tiger>() { new Tiger() };
```

That's legal. `List<Tiger>` implements `IEnumerable<Tiger>`, which is an interface and marked as safe for covariance, so it can be assigned to `IEnumerable<Animal>`.

You'll note that *there is no way to put a duck into a sequence of animals*, and therefore there is no way to put a duck into a sequence of tigers. *That's how we know that it is safe for covariance*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. My use case is a wrapper around a collection that needs to be of a certain base type. On the items in the collection certain operations need to be performed. I'm currently looking into splitting the Interface into getters and setters.